# How to Block data:image/encoded image requests through puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to block all media in puppeteer that includes encoded images, so far I was successful until I hit data:image type. they are not being blocked in puppeteer.

I tried many things like checking the url if it contains data:image, but still that request is not being aborted.

Here's my current code

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', (request) => {
    try{
        if (['image', 'media', 'png', 'jpeg', 'webp'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
            request.abort();
        } else if(request.url().startsWith('data:image')) {
            request.abort();
        } else {
            request.continue();
        }
    } catch(e){
        errors.push({
            message: "Interception Error",
            error_stack: e,
        });
    }
});
```

Tried this as well

```
if(request.url().startsWith('data:image')) {
    request.respond({
        ok: statusMessage === "OK",
        status: 200,
        body: '',
    });
}
```

This code is blocking normal images fine, but not being able to block base64 encoded images.
Here are some screenshots

[image: Blocking images with specific format]

[image: Allowing data:image to be served from memory]

Answer (score 1):

`data:image` images do not make net requests, they already have all their content inside the URL string. They are like inline scripts, you cannot block them by request interception. You can remove them after the page is rendered if they are not needed, but you cannot save their loading time as their content is included in the HTML source.